# Prove if a function is holomorphic, then its complex conjugate is holomorphic, by Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Given a function $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a disc $D(0,R)$, we want to prove that $g(z)= \overline {f(\bar z)}$ is holomorphic.

Below is my proof.

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\overline {f(\overline{z+h})}-\overline{f(\bar z)}}{h} =  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\overline {f(\overline{z+h})-\overline{f(\bar z)}}}{h} = \overline{\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(\overline{z+h})-\overline{f(\bar z)}}{\bar h}} = \overline{f'(\bar z)}$

Since $ f'(\bar z)$ exists, $g(z)= \overline {f(\bar z)}$ is holomorphic.

This question is actually an old one, but it is not duplicated, because I want to ask how to use Cauchy Riemann Equations to solve it. I mean, if I write $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and $g(z)=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)$, and try to show $g(z)$ is holomorphic by CREs, what should I do? The relationship between partial derivatives of $u(x,y)$ and $u(x,-y)$ is not just addition inverse. So what should I do next?

Also, I will be very grateful if you can help me to check my proof is correct.

So, actually my question is, how do I write $\frac {\partial} {\partial x } u(x,-y),\frac {\partial} {\partial y } u(x,-y)$ ?

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing in veryfying CR equations ? Do you know what is $\frac {\partial} {\partial x } u(x,-y)$ for example?

Comment: How do I write $\frac {\partial} {\partial x } u(x,-y)$ as $\frac {\partial} {\partial x } u(x,y)$? And is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x,y) = u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$ then
$g(x,y) = u(x,-y)-i v(x,-y) = a(x,y)+ib(x,y)$.

Then $ {\partial a(x,y) \over \partial x} = {\partial u(x,-y) \over \partial x}$,
$ {\partial a(x,y) \over \partial y} = -{\partial u(x,-y) \over \partial y}$,
$ {\partial b(x,y) \over \partial x} = -{\partial v(x,-y) \over \partial x}$
and
$ {\partial b(x,y) \over \partial y} = {\partial v(x,-y) \over \partial y}$.

Since ${\partial u(x,-y) \over \partial x} = {\partial v(x,-y) \over \partial y}$ and
${\partial u(x,-y) \over \partial y} = - {\partial v(x,-y) \over \partial x}$ you have the desired result.

Comment: Can you tell me if there're any mistakes in my proof by definition?

Comment: I would add one more step expanding $\overline{z+h} = \overline{z}+\overline{h}$.

Comment: I remember when using CREs to prove holomorphic functions, we need to say that the partial derivatives are continuous. Why we don't need to state here?

Comment: Well, you do, but since $f$ is analytic, then $u,v$ have continuous partials and so $a,b$ have continuous partials.